# Get all h4 tags inside List(View)

Tags: java, android, regex, list, jsoup

I'd like to get all h4 tags inside a specific div from a website and put them all inside a List(View).
This is a little bit code I tried, but it is not jsoup and I don't know why, but it only gets every second (or at least not every) h4 tag from the website.:

```
Pattern firstNewsPattern = Pattern.compile("<h3><strong>Aktuelle Meldungen</strong></h3>(.*?)<hr />");
    Pattern newsPattern = Pattern.compile("<hr />(.*?)<hr />");
    Pattern newsHeaderPattern = Pattern.compile("<h4>(.*?)</h4>");
    Pattern hrefPattern = Pattern.compile("href=\"(.*?)\"");
    Matcher newsHeader = null;
    Matcher href = null;

    Matcher firstNews = firstNewsPattern.matcher(html);
    if(firstNews.find()) {
        String content = firstNews.group(1).replace("./", "http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/");
        href = hrefPattern.matcher(content);
        while(href.find()) {
            String url = href.group(1);
            if(!url.contains("/")) {
                content = content.replace("href=\"" + url + "\"", "href=\"" + "http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/" + url + "\"");
            }
        }
        newsHeader = newsHeaderPattern.matcher(content);
        if(newsHeader.find())
            ret.add(new News(newsHeader.group(1).replaceAll("<(.*?)>", "").replaceAll("&#\\d{4};", ""), content));
    }

    Matcher news = newsPattern.matcher(html);
    while(news.find()) {
        String content = news.group(1).replace("./", "http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/");
        href = hrefPattern.matcher(content);
        while(href.find()) {
            String url = href.group(1);
            if(!url.contains("/")) {
                content = content.replace("href=\"" + url + "\"", "href=\"" + "http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/" + url + "\"");
            }
        }
        newsHeader = newsHeaderPattern.matcher(content);
        if(newsHeader.find())
            ret.add(new News(newsHeader.group(1).replaceAll("<(.*?)>", "").replaceAll("&#\\d{4};", ""), content));
    }
```

As this Snippet is not 100% written by me, I don't even understand it quite yet, so I wrote it again with jsoup on my own to get it working correctly:

```
List<News> ret = new ArrayList();
    getSharedPref sharedPrefMethod = new getSharedPref();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = sharedPrefMethod.getSharedPref();
    String result = "";
    try {
        String pattern = "(\\<h3>\\.\\<h3>) (\\</h3>)";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        String html1 = html0.replace(Pattern.quote("<em>Taxigutscheine !NEU! (zum Vergrößern auf das Bild klicken)</em>"), Matcher.quoteReplacement("<h4>Neue Taxigutscheine!</h4>"));
        String html2 = html1.replace(Pattern.quote("<h3>"), Matcher.quoteReplacement("<h4>"));
        String html3 = html2.replace(Pattern.quote("</h3>"), Matcher.quoteReplacement("</h4>"));
        String html4 = html3.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote("<h4>"), Matcher.quoteReplacement("<h3>"));
        String finalHTML = html4.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote("</h4>"), Matcher.quoteReplacement("</h3>"));
        Matcher m = r.matcher(finalHTML);
        if (m.find()) {
        } else {
        }
        result = finalHTML.substring(finalHTML.indexOf("<h3>") + 4, finalHTML.indexOf("</h3>"));
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("AktuelleMeldungenHeadline", result);
        editor.commit();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    result = sharedPref.getString("AktuelleMeldungenHeadline", "");
    ret.add(new News(result, result));
```

Can someone help me out here and get it working so I get every single h3 tag from div#content on [this website](http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/22-0-Aktuelle+Meldungen.html)?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you have some issues in your lower code... if you look at 2 = 1, 3=2, 4=3 --- you are changine everything from h3 to h4 and then immedietely changing it back again... Actually I just saw the replacefirst...

Comment: @Nefarii Yeah, I kinda messed it up, I sat quite a long time here trying to figure it out how that works.. I'm going to rewrite the whole thing, but I need help of someone of you, can you help me here?

Comment: Could you post an example incoming line? actually an incoming line and a finishing line